# Using a Scala symbol literal results in NoSuchMethod

Tags: scala, dsl, symbols, literals, nosuchmethoderror

I have recently begun using Scala.  I've written a DSL in it which can be used to describe a processing pipeline in [medici](http://medici.pnl.gov).  In my DSL, I've made use of symbols to signify an anchor, which can be used to put a fork (or a tee, if you prefer) in the pipeline.  Here's a small sample program that runs correctly:

```
object Test extends PipelineBuilder {
    connector("TCP") / Map("tcpProtocol" -> new DirectProtocol())
    "tcp://localhost:4858" --> "ByteToStringProcessor" --> Symbol("hello")
    "stdio://in?promptMessage=enter name:%20" --> Symbol("hello")
    Symbol("hello") --> "SayHello" / Map("prefix" -> "\n\t")  --> "stdio://out"
}
```

For some reason, when I use a symbol literal in my program, I get a NoSuchMethod exception at runtime:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Symbol.intern()Lscala/Symbol;
        at gov.pnnl.mif.scaladsl.Test$.<init>(Test.scala:7)
        at gov.pnnl.mif.scaladsl.Test$.<clinit>(Test.scala)
        at gov.pnnl.mif.scaladsl.Test.main(Test.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ObjectRunner.scala:75)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.withContextClassLoader(ObjectRunner.scala:49)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:74)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:154)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

This happens regardless of how the symbol is used.  Specifically, I've tried using the symbol in the pipeline, and in a simple `println('foo)` statement.

The question:  What could possibly cause a symbol literal's mere existence to cause a NoSuchMethodError?  In my DSL I am using an implicit function which converts symbols to instances of the Anchor class, like so:

```
    implicit def makeAnchor(a: Symbol):Anchor = anchor(a)
```

Sadly, my understanding of Scala is weak enough that I can't think of why that might be causing my NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: What's that --> operator take as an argument?

Comment: It's a method on a Node class that takes another Node as an argument.  It ends up calling the outer class's `connectNodes(a:Node, b:Node):Node` method.  Anchor extends Node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you are compiling with a different version of Scala than you have on the classpath at runtime.

### Checking the run-time version of Scala

Add the following to your main() method:

```
println(classOf[scala.Symbol].getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource)
```

This will tell you where you are loading the Scala library from, for example:

> (file:/Users/jason/usr/scala-2.8.0.RC2/lib/scala-library.jar )

### Checking the compile-time version of Scala

I don't know how you are invoking scalac. Assuming it's from the command line, run `scalac -version`.

Comment: I'm actually using maven to do the compile.  I'll try this and comment again with results.

Comment: Use `mvn -Dmaven.scala.displayCmd=true compile` to display the scalac command line.

Comment: I gave it a try, and the only 2 versions of scala I have on my system cause exactly the same error message.  Unless you can explain that, I think we can rule out scala versions being the problem.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see your other comment before I posted that.  Using that command, it looks like maven has provided a completely different scala version I couldn't find by hand: 2.6.  So the question now becomes: how do I tell maven to use scala 2.7?

Comment: Ahh, I found it in my pom.  I must have copied that straight out of an older example, I was requiring 2.6, and maven faithfully fetched it.  Looks like I'm good to go.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Could you possibly have multiple versions of Scala installed, as from the 2.7.1 source at least (http://scala-tools.org/scaladocs/scala-library/2.7.1/Symbol.scala.html) it doesn't look like Symbol has an intern method?

Comment: I also couldn't find an intern method on the symbol.  I do have scala 2.7.5 and 2.7.7 installed, but as far as I can tell it's only using 2.7.7.

Comment: In that case it'd be good to know what code the stack trace refers to as `at gov.pnnl.mif.scaladsl.Test$.<init>(Test.scala:7)`. Assuming it's the code you were referring to, is it possible to post it here?

Comment: Effectively, it's this: `"tcp://localhost:4858" --> "ByteToStringProcessor" --> 'hello`.  The only difference between the program that works and the program that doesn't is `Symbol("hello")` vs `'hello`.