# NoSuchMethodError when attempting to implicitly convert a java to scala collection

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections

I started to receive this kind of error in my code:

```
Message:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:scala.collection.JavaConversions
$.asScalaSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Lscala/collection/mutable/Set
```

and then I see a long screen of stacktrace of uninteresting nature, which is triggered on this piece of code:

```
edited.authors.toSeq
```

where `authors` is a `java.lang.Set`.  Does anybody know why is this happening? It's a runtime failure and not a compile one.

Comment: This kind of error can usually be attributed to having the wrong version of the Scala library on the classpath.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863091/using-a-scala-symbol-literal-results-in-nosuchmethod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a library which has been compiled with **2.8.1** from the **2.8.0** runtime