# Pig-Scala UDF exception- ScalaObject not found

Tags: scala, classpath, classnotfoundexception, apache-pig

I have a scala .class file that I convert to a jar and try to `register` to a pig script. It is able to find that class now BUT it throws a `ClassNotFoundException` for `scala.ScalaObject`.

I notice that there is a scala.ScalaObject.class entry in the `scala-library` jar in the `littlepiggy/lib` folder.

**Question 1**

Shouldn't this jar be directly accessible anyways? Or do I have to add this path to an equivalent of a CLASSPATH for Pig?

**Question 2**

After this, I forcefully registered that jar as well.

I got this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.JavaConversions$.asScalaIterator(Ljava/util/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator
```

This doesn't look right to me. Any ideas?

PS - This source suggests that I should include the scala-library jar but Pig should already be able to find it and anyways, its not really working for me.
(http://mehack.com/levenshtein-distance-function-for-pig-and-had-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer's here. Should have checked out a more exhaustive set of keywords.

[NoSuchMethodError when attempting to implicitly convert a java to scala collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393946/nosuchmethoderror-when-attempting-to-implicitly-convert-a-java-to-scala-collecti)

I was using different scala versions to build the class file and then in pig.

Thanks!